# How read a file inside the CRX file into a string?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to read the data from a file that is distributed with my CRX (it's in a subfolder `myfiles`) into a javascript variable. (It is *not* on the filesystem. It's inside the crx)

I understand I can use XMLHttpRequest, but what would the url be? Would it just be a relative one? or a `file:///WHAT_GOES_HERE/myfile.txt`? Since this is a packaged app, what would go after the "file:///"?

*I don't want to use `chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry` because that requires Chrome 29 or later and some of my users might not have that version*

How would I do this?

**This is a chrome packaged app, not extension**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the URL you should use [chrome.runtime.getURL](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime.html#method-getURL).

Comment: And with that url, I should be able to read the file contents via XmlHttpRequest?

Comment: @DonRhummy yes, you should. Check also this answer where they use a relative URL http://stackoverflow.com/a/15983919/1507998