# How to read and get Propertyfile values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, properties-file

I'm developing project based on html and JavaScript. I have values in `info.properties` file.

How can I get and use those `info.properties` file values in my JavaScript function. This is the values I have in my file:

```
msg.confirm     =Okie?
msg.alert       =Cancel.
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: @RGraham,Could you please provide me any sample code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read properties file using jquery or java script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416185/read-properties-file-using-jquery-or-java-script)

Comment: @RGraham,I'm new to this,i have not understood that answer.so I'm taking help from you.

Comment: I don't think so you can read directly from property file in javascript.. You can read through server side