# read the label from properties file in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a certain piece of code in javascript file and in this the labe is hard coded, instead of hard code label i need to read it from a properties.utf8 file. I am trying out few possibilities but the label is not showing up as what mentioned in properties file

this is the existing piece of code
 html.push(" Person Name");

in this Person name is hard coded, instead of this i want to read it from a Key in properties file, i have already created a key in properties.utf file, PROJECT_PERSON_NAME= Person Name

and i am using this key to get the label
html.push("PROJECT_PERSON_NAME");

but this does not seems to be working out, can you please suggest, how this can be accomplished.
I am new to html, css, styling, UI stuff. Please help

Comment: please provide some code example so we can have a better idea of whats going on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25533857/1982680 try this out or http://blog.ropardo.ro/2010/07/15/two-options-to-show-properties-from-a-properties-file/