# Node JS - read file properties

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, file-properties

I'm developing a Desktop Application with NWJS and I need to get the file properties of an .exe File.

I've tried using the npm properties module https://github.com/gagle/node-properties, but I get an empty Object.

```
properties.parse('./unzipped/File.exe', { path: true }, function (err, obj) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            console.log(obj);
        });
```

I need to get the "File version" Property:

[image: File Properties]

I've also tried using fs.stats and no luck.
Any ideas?

Comment: > there is an another way already
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984615/4348530](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984615/4348530)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you want to write some native C module, there is hacky way to get this done easily: using windows `wmic` command. This is the command to get version (found by googling):

```
wmic datafile where name='c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe' get Version
```

so you can just run this command in node to get the job done:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec

exec('wmic datafile where name="c:\\\\windows\\\\system32\\\\notepad.exe" get Version', function(err,stdout, stderr){
 if(!err){
   console.log(stdout)// parse this string for version
 }
});
```

Comment: $ wmic datafile where name="C:\Development\nwjs\sistelupdater\unzipped\StaClient.exe" get Version
Node - USUARIO-PC
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query

Comment: use double '\\' for path separator. I'm not familiar with this command either. Try google for details

Comment: I used double backlashes also.. but still

Comment: Ok,, for some reason it works from the cmd console... but not from any other console and neither from node

Comment: in node, did you use 4 '\' ?

Comment: there we go :D i was getting part of my path from a variable in which there where single '\' ... it works now :D

Answer (score 3):

If you want the properties provided as an object, you can use `get-file-properties`. It uses `wmic` under the hood, but takes care of parsing the output into an easy to use typed object for your application's consumption.

```
import { getFileProperties, WmicDataObject } from 'get-file-properties'

async function demo() {
  // Make sure to use double backslashes in your file path
  const metadata: WmicDataObject = await getFileProperties('C:\\path\\to\\file.txt')
  console.log(metadata.Version)
}
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of `get-file-properties`

Comment: Worked for me in node js. Can this Run in Linux?

Comment: @NyagakaEnock As far as I know this isn't needed in Linux, since Node's native fs.stat() will get any file properties that are available in Linux. I could be wrong on that, but I've dug around and haven't found any real clear equivalent to the data that WMIC.exe pulls for the file in Windows, or mdls on macOS. I'm hoping to add cross-platform support for the get-file-properties module, just haven't had time yet.