# Ng-repeat is not showing data coming from config.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a>cakes</a></li>
    <li ng-repeat="menu in menuItems">
        <a>{{menu}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Js:

```
$http.get('resources/config.js').then(function (data) {
    $scope.menuBar = data.menuBar;
    var menuItems = [];
    menuItems = $scope.menuBar;
    console.log(menuItems);
  });
```

config.js:

```
data = {
    logo : 'My App',
    menuBar : ["Cakes", "Chocolates","Flowers", "Toys", "Special Gifts"],
    view : ["#cake","#chocolates","#flowers","#toys", "#gifts"]
}
```

I am new to angular js. I am trying to pull data from config file which has menu items defined under menuBar.

I want to display all items in ul-li format.
But somehow its not working.Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate `$scope.menuItems` which is the name you are using in your template.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain me in little bit detail.

Comment: In html template, you are iterating over items in menuItem. So you'd need to set menuItem property of scope, to be able to use it in your view. The fact that my or other answerer's suggestion didn't work probably means that your code is not bound to the template. Here is an example: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp.

Comment: yeah I tried according to tutorial but again its not working.

Answer (score 0):

The array you go over in ng-repeat must be defined over a scope, therefore in order for angular to know what "menuItems" is, it must be defined as a cope.

Try changing the ng-repeat to `"menu in menuBar"`,
or in your JS change `menuBar` to `menuItems`.

Comment: I tried both the way but its not working.and no error is also coming.

Comment: config.js is invalid json. Remove the "data =" from the beginning.

Comment: Here is a full working example. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/ybEcq60iRy2zkdbWL6L4?p=preview

Make sure you validate your json using one of the many online tools you can find. For example you were using single quotes instead of double.

Comment: actually config.js is not a json. I am trying to remove hardcode data from my main code and trying to pull these property data instaed of that hardcord data. i refering an example from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310951/how-to-read-a-properties-file-in-javascript-from-project-directory

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$scope.menuItems = $scope.menuBar;
```

You have

```
menuItems = $scope.menuBar;
```

Unless there's a specific reason to have $scope.menuBar, you can just skip it and go directly with:

```
 $http.get('resources/config.js').then(function (data) {
        var menuItems = [];
        $scope.menuItems = data.menuBar;
 });
```

Not sure of the, ahem -- scope -- of your app ;) but if it's anything beyond super simple, you will want to use a Service for the data so you give access to the data to multiple controllers by injecting it as a dependency, for example:

```
app.service("DataService", function($http){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.get('resources/config.js').then(function (data) {
       deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    this.getData = function(){
       return deferred.promise;
    }
});

app.controller('someCtrl',['DataService', '$scope',function(DataService, $scope){
     var menuItems = [];
      $scope.menuItems = DataService.getData().menuBar;
}]);
```

Comment: no I cannot use service here. Because I am my config.js ia a property file where I have to pull my data to be placed in main code to remove hard code data.

Comment: Just added it in case you wanted; you said you were new to Angular. Lmk if the rest works for you.

Comment: Can you set up a plunker or something so we can see the context?